# How does one prove that $ABA^{−1} = B$ given that A is an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that $ABA^{-1}=B.$

My intuition tells me that it's right, but I can't prove it. I've tried some variations of:

If, $ABA^{−1} = B$

then, $(A^{−1})(ABA^{−1}) = (A^{−1})(B).$

Hence, $BA^{−1} = A^{−1}B.$

But this is not true since matrix multiplication isn't commutative. Does this mean that the statement is false?

Comment: What are A and B?  Matrices?  Over what field?

Comment: Just take $A=I$ how can it be right?

Comment: What you wrote is incomprehensible unless one guesses a lot of things.. What sort of objects are $A$ and $B$? What are you trying to prove? We know math here and are willing to help you, but we certainly do not read minds.

Comment: @Shashi think it's supposed to be $ABA^{-1}$ not $ABA-1$

Comment: @Sashi I'd guess that the -1 is supposed to be an exponent.

Comment: Ow.. You guys read minds better than I do!

Comment: We may arguably say that linear algebra is the discipline that studies the consequences of the fact that the identity you've written does not hold.

Comment: The statement is false.  Take any pair of matrices $A$ and $B$ which do not commute and you will see the statement is false.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, it is not true in general.

Let 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then $ABA^{-1} \neq B.$

Of course, if $A$ and $B$ were commuting matrices, then it would be true.

Comment: This solution is better than mine, because it works for arbitrary $\Bbb K$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are matrices over reals and $A$ is invertible. It is false.

Take $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, $B \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and check.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is: Does $ABA^{-1}=B$ hold for arbitrary matrices $A,B\in M_n(\Bbb{K})$ the answer is no. Take for example $$\Bbb{K}=\Bbb{R}\text{ (or any other field of characteristic }\neq 2),\ A=A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $$ABA^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\neq B.$$

Notice that $ABA^{-1}=B$ holds if and only if $AB=BA$ holds (by multiplying $A$ from the right on both sides).